# any way to launch extensions ? chrome.management.launchApp does not allow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to run another extension from my extension; chrome has a very nice management api and a method for that but chrome.management.launchApp does not allow for it, it throws "is not an App" error. Yes it's not an App, it's an extension.

You can enable/disable/uninstall! extension but cannot launch it. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: An extension does not have an entry point, so requesting to "launch" an extension does not make sense. Can you give a clearer description of what you want to achieve?

Comment: it's not related about my achievements, but if it will make clear; i can launch "Turn Off the Lights" extension when my (supposing) "Change your mood up to weather" extension with some other functionality.

Comment: So you just want to enable/disable an extension. Use the [`chrome.management.setEnabled`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-setEnabled) method.

Comment: @RobW as is said in question "You can enable/disable/uninstall extension but cannot launch it" enabling is very different feature.

Comment: As said in my first comment, extensions cannot be "launched". You could replicate the functionality and activate it within your extension though.

Comment: "Extensions are small software programs that can modify and enhance the functionality of the Chrome browser. You write them using web technologies such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS."
i had thought that software programs can be lauched. sorry lets say it "activate" if it will make more sense